# How to update XML element text using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to use PowerShell to update an XML element name/text to something else.

```xml
<add connectionString=" " accessKey=" " abortConnect="false" ssl="true">
```

This is super basic but I need to use PowerShell to update the text 'connectionString' to 'host' for my scenario.  This is in a web.config file and so uses XML.

Comment: Is there only 1 `<add />` node with the `connectionString` attribute? Perhaps show us the full xml document you're trying to edit

Comment: [stackoverflow://\[xml\]+add+attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxml%5D+add+attribute), [stackoverflow://\[xml\]+remove+attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxml%5D+remove+attribute)

Comment: There are other connection strings so I don't want to edit those.  This is the element path via powershell:

$xml.configuration.location.'system.web'.sessionState.providers.add